# What is the difference between StackExchange.Redis and StackExchange.Redis.StrongName?

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

While I was following Azure [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/) for how to use Redis Cache in Azure Portal I noticed this note:

> If you prefer to use a strong-named version of the StackExchange.Redis
>   client library, choose StackExchange.Redis.StrongName; otherwise
>   choose StackExchange.Redis.

What is the strong-named ? and what is the proc and cons ? How to decide if I need it or not in my application ?

Comment: [You can chcek this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354129/why-use-strong-named-assemblies) [and this documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8874/Strong-Names-Explained)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you need a strongly named Redis library? In all likelihood, especially  if you never even encountered this term, the answer is *no*. But read on.

What is strongly named?

- it's a .NET specific thing
- you can choose to sign your assembly with a cryptographic key
- this makes it possible to verify that you are actually loading/running something you expect to load/run
- the "strong name" includes the cryptographic signature together with the the usual name, version and things like that.

Do you ever need strong names?

- probably not unless you have specific reasons. Some of these may be:
- historic (we used to sign our assemblies and why change now)
- corporate policies
- special circumstances such as something else you are using requires strong names (it used to be a requirement to have strong name if you wanted to add something to the GAC)
- possibly security considerations

Is it a good idea to sign your assemblies?

- there are a lot of divided opinions
- very often strong names are a pain in so many ways with questionable benefits
- it has been a trend lately to not use strong names unless you really must

Do *you* need a strongly named Redis library?

- unless you decide or have to sign your own application which uses Redis library you don't
- the strong names version of Redis library is identical to the other one
- it exists solely for the reason to make lives of those who need to use strong names easier

Answer (score 17):

Aside from the signed vs unsigned assemblies argument, the [RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider) has a dependency on *StackExchange.Redis.StrongName*

So if you want to use RedisSessionStateProvider, choose the StrongName version unless you want to have two dependencies.

**Update**: As @Matei_Radu has pointed out, [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis) also has a dependency on *StackExchange.Redis.StrongName*

You can only have a dependency on one (either signed or unsigned) in a single assembly, but if you have multiple projects, you might have dependencies on both.  It may simplify things to keep only the signed version to avoid problems

Comment: I find this answer covers a much more practical scenario than the real strong name usage.

Comment: Also, `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis` has a dependency on the strong named Redis library. But a rather strange behavior appears: Even if i have `StackExchange.Redis` installed, I have to install the strong named library and uninstall it in order for my `SignalR` server to work. Is there anything more in the package? And why does it work after uninstalling? (I can't keep both `StackExchange.Redis` and `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` since there are conflicts)?

Comment: @Matei_Radu because both assemblies provide the exact same classes so you can't reference both in the same assembly (and have it work)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that they contain the same classes, but does the strong-named version contain anything more (except the signing stuff) ?

Comment: @Matei_Radu no, it is the exact same source, except signed. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis has a dependency on the StrongName version thus you need the StrongName dependency for SignalR to work

Comment: Yeah, I thought that since `StackExchange.Redis` has the same types and is the same source, I might get away with using it:) Thanks, I solved it.

Comment: It looks like the Strongname version of the library is no longer getting updates - the regular version has been updated to v2, while the strong name is still at v1.2.6.   Likewise, the RedisSessionStateProvider has also beenn updated (as of v4) to have the regular StackExchange.Redis v2 as a dependancy.     This thread still comes up in google, so worth an update even though the thread is old.

Comment: The new version of [`Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider`](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/107) doesn't rely on `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName`

Answer (score 3):

The strong name version is for developers who use strongly named assemblies in sharepoint and com+ development. The nuget package dev himself says that there is no simple answer for this question. Read the blog post here http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/06/snk-we-need-to-talk.html

Comment: Thanks for great contribution to the discussion. Just to be clear, the use of strong names is not specific ONLY to SharePoint and COM+ development.