# SignalR scaleout backplane using Redis

Tags: asp.net, redis, signalr, signalr-backplane

I am using SignalR with Redis backplane scaleout. Now, the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis` package has a dependency to `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName`.

Since I was already using Redis in my application, I have the `StackExchange.Redis` package installed.

When I install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis` and choose not to install the dependency to the strong-named package for Redis, my application stops working (the client doesn't connect to the server - it tries every method of connecting, falling back to `longPolling`, but fails).

The strange thing is that if I install `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` (at this point I have both the strong-named version and the normal one - so I have duplicate identifiers for every type from Redis) - I uninstall the strong-named package and everything starts working. (even if the strong-named package doesn't have any dependencies).

My question - does the strong-named package contain some specific stuff that SignalR uses (and why does the application work after removing it?)

Thanks!

Comment: "It may simplify things to keep only the signed version to avoid problems" -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/31529668/188926

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the strong name redis dll left in a bin folder. Do a clean build and see if it still works.

The solution is to move over the the StackExchange.Redis.StrongName package.