# Install dll's to gac with WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, gac

I need to install Microsoft Practices enterprise library into the GAC on a production server. I have read endless articles that state the way to do this is by creating an msi with wix but I can't for the life of me figure out how it's done. Is there a way to create a simple application that references the enterprise library and installs it to the gac? Nothing else needs to be installed.

Comment: Installing to the GAC isn't difficult provided the assembly has a strong name. You just mark it as a GAC file. Are you in a big company? Check if there is a **packaging / distribution department**, they are sure to have a package ready made? I would start from there. If not there could be existing packages online (haven't been exposed to this particular library - at least not for years). [WiX Quick Start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Comment: I haven't found any existing packages online unfortunately and we don't have a packaging/distribution department. An msi is available internally but that doesn't install to the GAC and no one is sure where it came from. Is there a way to make the existing msi install the DLL's to the GAC?

Answer (score 2):

IsWiX installs GlobalParams.dll to the GAC.  You can find the source code here:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix/blob/master/Installer/IsWiXNewAddInMM/IsWiXNewAddInMMcustom.wxs

```
 <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Directory Id="GlobalAssemblyCache" Name="GlobalAssemblyCache">
        <Component Id="globalparams" Guid="{B07FF430-AAB4-49E6-8035-60142942F325}" Permanent="yes">
          <File Id="globalparams" Source="..\Deploy\IsWiXNewAddIn\GlobalParams.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

As I recall, the directory ID doesn't really matter.  Windows installer doesn't use these in terms of the GAC.   The trick is 1) the DLL must have a strong name  2)  The Assembly=".net" attribute will populate the proper MSIAssembly tables so that MSI will use the MsiPublishAssemblies action to interact with fusion and register the assemblies in the correct GAC.

Answer (score 0):

If only I knew the library... Let me jot down some quick options in addition to **Chris Painter's** answer:

---

***NuGet***: [Seems to be a NuGet package here?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn169621%28v%3Dpandp.10%29)

***Dark.exe***: You can also use the WiX toolkit and its **`dark.exe`** binary to decompile an existing MSI and then tweak it and compile a new MSI. The required cleanup of the WiX markup is not trivial, but possible to do. A trained packager could certainly do it. [**WiX Quick Start Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

***GAC***: Installing to the GAC requires a [strong name for the assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies) (signed) in question ([more on strong naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354129/why-use-strong-named-assemblies)) and then you simply set the Assembly attribute to **`".net"`** as explained by **Painter** in his answer:

- [**`WiX Documentation: File Element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html) (notice how the **`AssemblyApplication`** attribute should be unset).
- Actual markup:

```xml
    <File Source="MyFile.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" />
```

---

***Some Links***: Maybe have a quick read of these links.

- [Enterprise Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648951(v=pandp.10))
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Enterprise_Library
- https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/enterprise-library